# I can install pygamebut as soon as I try to install pgzero it allways ends with an error code

Tags: python, installation

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Thomas\pgzero_env\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5voo4hii\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5voo4hii\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3wy10uc8'
     cwd: C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5voo4hii\pygame\
Complete output (17 lines):


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5voo4hii\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5voo4hii\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5voo4hii\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5voo4hii\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the working of Python **EOF Error**:

1. BaseException class is the base class of Exception class which in turn inherits the EOFError class.
2. *EOFError is not an error technically but it is an exception. When the in-built functions such as input() function or read() function returns a string which is empty without reading any data, then EOFError exception is raised.*
3. This exception is raised when our program is trying to obtain something and do modifications to it but when it fails to read any data and returns a string which is empty, EOFError exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue.  The command:

```
pip install pygame
```

installed completely without issues.   However,

```
pip install pgzero
```

gave me that big long list of errors that you got.

Also, I was using using Python 3.9.0.

I just uninstalled it completely, and then installed 3.8.7.   Both PYGAME and PGZERO installed correctly!   Get it from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Answer (score 0):

Also - even though I got both modules installed, my simple program wouldn't work:

```
import pgzrun
def draw():
    screen.draw.text("Hello", topleft=(10,10))
pgzrun.go()
```

I'd get all kinds of weird errors.  I found the answer at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html?page=4&pageSize=10&sort=votes&type=problem.

I typed this in to change the version of numpy:

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Then my code ran just fine.